# Android development. CardView not working?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F3F3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dersName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Unfortunately,ProjectTry has stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhT2G.png)

Also I added  this code

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

**compilation was successfull but, it gives me Unfortunately ProjectTry has stopped**
*How can i overcome this problem?* When I type

Comment: show logcat error

Comment: as @Rasel says show your logcat

Comment: if you have this implementation `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` then you should be using this `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`. learn more about migrating to androidx topics https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after updating 
my library to androidX

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

To overcome this problem.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dersName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:elevation="5dp">
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your manifest file has a android:hardwareAccelerated="false" line, delete it.

see for details
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html?hl=ru

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.